# what does "in person" mean?

Tags: word-usage

[In dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/person), they said

> if you do something in person, you go somewhere and do it yourself,
> instead of doing something by letter, asking someone else to do it
> etc:
>
> You have to sign for it in
> person.

But what about "**You are taller in person than in pictures**" & "**you're much paler in person**"

So "**in person**" means "**yourself**"?

Comment: If you do something in person *often* means **going** to a specific place and being visible (in person) to others. To be taller "in person" .... means to be appear taller in "real life" than in a photo. The person has *physically gone* to meet someone face to face.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is too basic for this site and ELL. The answer is in the dictionary entry which the OP cited.

Answer (score 1):

*in person* means - **by ​meeting with someone ​rather than ​talking on the ​phone, e-mailing, or writing to the person:** according to the Cambridge Dictionary.
This basically means being present physically.
By "**You are taller in person than in pictures**" & "**you're much paler in person**" means the subject is present physically and is hence saying the person is much taller when he/she sees that person physically rather than in pictures.
Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

`in person` means face to face conversation / physical presence .

**For Example** When submitting any University application you might come across lines such as .

1. All the documents must submitted in person.
2. Email your Cv with necessary documents , shortlisted candidates must come for an interview in person .

Hope it helped .